# How to mount/unmount flash disk with using hal,dbus in python?

Tags: python, dbus

i need to mount and unmount flash drive in my code -written with python- without using command line or os module.

how can i mount/unmount flash drive with using dbus ( also hal)?

Comment: You might get better answers on Superuser or Ubuntu...

Comment: I'm not even sure if the answer is in `os`, but why would you disallow probably the second-most common stdlib?

Comment: i intended to use os module for using command line in my program, but it doesnt satisfy my requirements. i need to mount/unmount flash disk with using hal and dbus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/hal) for hal(in maintenance mode) or [here](http://hal.freedesktop.org/docs/udisks/ref-dbus.html) for udisks